ASP.NET Core Site won't start because it can't resolve database context even if it's added to services
Suddenly my site doesn't start, it can't resolve AssesDbContext when resolving IRepoFactory. I'm not sure what's wrong since all the database services are added at the start of config.
I get the following error:
Cannot resolve 'SL.Assets.Components.Repo.IRepoFactory' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'SL.Assets.Components.Data.AssetsDbContext'.
Config:
_ = builder.Services
    .AddHttpContextAccessor()
    .AddTransient<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>()
    .AddDbContext<AssetsDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(AssetsStatics.ConnectionString))
    .AddDbContext<AssetsClientDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(AssetsStatics.ClientConnectionString))
    .AddTransient<IAssetsDbContext, AssetsDbContext>()
    .AddTransient<IAssetsClientDbContext, AssetsClientDbContext>()
    .AddTransient<IDbContextAccessor, DbContextAccessor>()
    .AddTransient<IAssetsConfigAccessor, AssetsConfigAccessor>()
    .AddTransient<IExpressionFactory, ExpressionFactory>()
    .AddTransient<IClientExpressionFactory, ClientExpressionFactory>()
    .AddTransient<ILocalizationAccessor, LocalizationAccessor>()
    .AddTransient<IUtilityAccessor, UtilityAccessor>()
    .AddTransient<IUrlHelperFactory, UrlHelperFactory>()
    .AddTransient<IRepoFactory, RepoFactory>()
    .AddTransient<IExpressionFactory, ExpressionFactory>();

RepoFactory:
public interface IRepoFactory
{
    IRepoBase this[RepoType type] { get; }
    IRepoCoreBase this[RepoCoreType type] { get; }
}

public class RepoFactory(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IActionContextAccessor actionContext, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelper, IExpressionFactory expFact, IAssetsConfigAccessor config, IDbContextAccessor dbContext, IWebHostEnvironment environment) : IRepoFactory
{
    public IRepoBase this[RepoType type] 
    {
        get
        {
            ....
        }
    }

    public IRepoCoreBase this[RepoCoreType type]
    {
        get
        {
            IRepoCoreBase? result = default;

            switch(type)
            {
                case RepoCoreType.TagHelper:
                    result = new TagHelperRepo(httpContext, actionContext, environment, config.Assets.Config, urlHelper);
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

Any ideas?

Please provide your AssetsDbContext class.

@ojonasplima thanks but I figured it out! it was a middleware issue

This middleware component was the issue. I moved the dependency injection from class constructor to the Invoke method.
Old:
public sealed class SetSignIn(RequestDelegate next, IRepoFactory repoFactory)
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        ....
    }
}

New:
public sealed class SetSignIn(RequestDelegate next)
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IRepoFactory repoFactory)
    {
        ....
    }
}

